# Xpath Package in Sublime Text 3 DOESN't work

Tags: xpath, plugins, sublimetext3

I just installed the Xpath package control in ST3, but there is no other option than "Set Syntax: Xpath 1.0" in Command Pallete, I have tried to reinstall the package but it still doesn't work. Any Solution would be apreciated.

Update:

here is my console looks like:

```
warning: mnemonic t not found in menu caption Tools
warning: mnemonic c not found in menu caption CSV
startup time: 1.0816
first paint time: 1.0826
reloading plugin Default.arithmetic
reloading plugin Default.auto_indent_tag
reloading plugin Default.block
reloading plugin Default.colors
reloading plugin Default.comment
reloading plugin Default.convert_color_scheme
reloading plugin Default.convert_syntax
reloading plugin Default.copy_path
reloading plugin Default.delete_word
reloading plugin Default.detect_indentation
reloading plugin Default.duplicate_line
reloading plugin Default.echo
reloading plugin Default.exec
reloading plugin Default.fold
reloading plugin Default.font
reloading plugin Default.goto_line
reloading plugin Default.history_list
reloading plugin Default.indentation
reloading plugin Default.install_package_control
reloading plugin Default.kill_ring
reloading plugin Default.mark
reloading plugin Default.new_templates
reloading plugin Default.open_context_url
reloading plugin Default.open_in_browser
reloading plugin Default.pane
reloading plugin Default.paragraph
reloading plugin Default.paste_from_history
reloading plugin Default.profile
reloading plugin Default.quick_panel
reloading plugin Default.rename
reloading plugin Default.run_syntax_tests
reloading plugin Default.save_on_focus_lost
reloading plugin Default.scroll
reloading plugin Default.set_unsaved_view_name
reloading plugin Default.settings
reloading plugin Default.show_scope_name
reloading plugin Default.side_bar
reloading plugin Default.sort
reloading plugin Default.swap_line
reloading plugin Default.switch_file
reloading plugin Default.symbol
reloading plugin Default.transform
reloading plugin Default.transpose
reloading plugin Default.trim_trailing_white_space
reloading plugin Default.ui
reloading plugin CSS.css_completions
reloading plugin Diff.diff
reloading plugin HTML.encode_html_entities
reloading plugin HTML.html_completions
reloading plugin ShellScript.ShellScript
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.00-package_control
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.10-lxml
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.50-pytz
reloading plugin CSV.csvplugin
reloading plugin DataConverter.DataConverter
reloading plugin InsertDate.insert_date
reloading plugin Package Control.1_reloader
reloading plugin Package Control.2_bootstrap
reloading plugin Package Control.Package Control
reloading plugin Split Line.split_line
reloading plugin Tabify.Tabify
reloading plugin xpath.lxml_parser
reloading plugin xpath.sublime_helper
reloading plugin xpath.sublime_input
reloading plugin xpath.sublime_input_quickpanel
reloading plugin xpath.sublime_input_view
reloading plugin xpath.sublime_lxml
reloading plugin xpath.tests
reloading plugin xpath.xpath
plugins loaded
Package Control: No updated packages
```

and I also installed CSV,DataConverter,InsertDate and Tabify in case those plugins probably make my Xpath plugin stopped working.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Sublime console (`View > Show Console`) that might indicate that something has gone wrong?

Comment: Hi @Odatnurd Thanks for replying, I have uploaded the resources, hope it helps to solve the problem

Comment: We did some trouble shooting last night and determined that the package is broken for Linux users that are using a development build in the latest series, but based on your console output above, that does not apply to you. The commands in the command palette are only available inside of XML files though. Are you seeing them missing even in that case?

Comment: I'm working on thousands lines of data so I convert the files to .txt files, i didn't notice that! I am seeing them now! it works thanks @OdatNurd xx